# Ubuntu 18.04 mouse pointer issue [ Jumping here and there ]

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo, hp, mouse-pointer

I Installed **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** on **HP Probook**. I have an issue. The mouse pointer jumps here and there like crazy, when I'm searching something on Google new tabs get open in browser, when I'm coding pointer jumps few lines away. I love to use **Ubuntu** but this a bad experience, even as I type this question mouse pointer jumps away :-(

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the pointer behaves if you were to attach a regular mouse and this erratic behavior is limited to trackpad activity.  Likely then you will want a different driver for your trackpad.  If you can locate your exact model number, you may be able to use that to search for the correct driver (or at least instructions for solving this erratic behavior on using your current driver or some generic driver).  If a connected mouse behaves the same way, this is not the best path.